# Display a users full name in Master Page

Tags: branding

I have figured out how to display users login name ...

```
<asp:LoginName runat="server" id="LoginName"></asp:LoginName>
```

But how do I display the users full name?

Thanks ... Mike

[EDIT]

I think I may have found out what I need using jQuery SPServices.

[SPServices get user details](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation)

I will report back :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep. SPServices is the best way to do that (but sounds like you figured it out already!):

```
var userFirstName= $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "FirstName"});
var userFirstName= $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "LastName"});
var userFullName = userFirstName + " " + userLastName;
```

Comment: Actually ... I did it using SharePoint Portal Web Controls. I registered the tags and used this tag <SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="FirstName" ApplyFormatting="false" runat="server"/> Would that be wrong?